# Save settings pages for WordPress Plugin and use variables in the frontend

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a Slider plugin for educational purposes to get used with the WP PHP ecosystem.
As of now i have built the file structure of the Plugin and created a nice slide show using Bootstrap.
In the continuation i want to create a settings page in order to upload the slider images and the appropriate text for each one of them.
I have created a settings page and the appropriate form.
I need to understand how can i pass the POST variables in my template.html file and replace the src="..." images with them.

The options.php file is:

```
            <?php

            //Plugin Options Menu

            /** Adds menu in the WP admin area*/
            add_action('admin_menu', 'sd_cool_plugin_create_menu');

            //create menu
            function sd_cool_plugin_create_menu() {

                //create new top-level menu
                add_menu_page('My Cool Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) );

                //call register settings function
                add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
            }

            add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sd_slider_settings' );
            add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );

            //register settings
            function register_mysettings() { // whitelist options
                register_setting( 'sd-option-group', 'new_option_name' );
                register_setting( 'sd-option-group', 'some_other_option' );
                register_setting( 'sd-option-group', 'option_etc' );
            }

            //add icon


            /** Step 1. */
            function sd_slider_settings() {
                add_options_page( 'SD Slider Settings', 'SD Slider', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'sd_plugin_options' );
                add_menu_page('SD Slider Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('stylesheet_directory')."/images/logo.png");

            }

            /** Step 3. */
            function sd_plugin_options() {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
                    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
                }
                echo '<div class="wrap">';
                echo '<h1>SD Slider Plugin Options</h1>';
                echo '</div>';?>
                
                <form method="post" action="template.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <?php settings_fields( 'sd-option-group' ); ?>

            <!-- settings input form -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- 1st image -->
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Choose the 1st image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="image1">
            <br>
                <label for="fname">Headline:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline1" name="headline1"><br><br>
            <br>
            <label for="fname">Caption:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline1" name="headline1"><br><br>
            <br>
            <!-- 2nd image -->

                <label for="exampleFormControlFile2">Choose the 2nd image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile2" name="image2">
            <br>
                <label for="fname">Headline:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline2" name="headline2"><br><br>
            <br>
            <label for="fname">Caption:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline2" name="headline2"><br><br>

            <!-- 3rd image -->
            <br>
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile3">Choose the 3rd image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile3" name="image3">
            <br>
                <label for="fname">Headline:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline3" name="headline3"><br><br>
            <br>
            <label for="fname">Caption:</label>
            <input type="text" id="headline3" name="headline3"><br><br>

            <?php submit_button(); ?>

            </div>
            </form>

            <?
            }

            //Plugin Options Menu End
            ?>



            <?php
            // create custom plugin settings menu
            add_action('admin_menu', 'my_cool_plugin_create_menu');

            function my_cool_plugin_create_menu() {

                //create new top-level menu
                add_menu_page('My Cool Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) );

                //call register settings function
                add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
            }


            function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
                //register our settings
                register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
                register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
                register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
            }

            function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() {
            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Your Plugin Name</h1>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name') ); ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('some_other_option') ); ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ); ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
                <?php submit_button(); ?>

            </form>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

```js
var $ = jQuery;


$(document).ready(function(){

    var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel');
    var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);

    $('#page').prepend("<div id='slider-container'></div>");
    $("#slider-container").load("wp-content/plugins/slider-plugin/template.html") ;
  });
```

```html
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
<img width="100%" height="100%" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Fdemo%2FResponsive-Full-Width-jQuery-Image-Slider-Plugin-skdslider%2Fslides%2F1.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
<img width="100%" height="100%" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jqueryscript.net%2Fdemo%2FResponsive-Full-Width-jQuery-Image-Slider-Plugin-skdslider%2Fslides%2F1.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

I am using the options.php code from [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

The Carousel comes from [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/carousel/)

This is the [last Git Push](https://github.com/xbass540/sd-slider-plugin/tree/session_variables)